# Import new project on Vercel doesn't work

Tags: next.js, vercel

I want to import my Git Repository (of my Next.js project) on Vercel but when I click on "import", nothing happens, just a white page on my browser which doesn't do anything...

When I look at the Console, there is an error :

> " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of
> undefined "

I don't know what to do, I've deployed projects on Vercel in the past and it worked perfectly.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello! Lee from Vercel - is this still happening for you?

Comment: Hello, it doens't work with Chrome but it works with another browser. I don't know why, maybe I have to reinstall Chrome.
Thank you !